# Python: count time of watching video

Tags: python, video, youtube, video-streaming

I have a task, connected with detection time of watching video.
If I watch the video, for example `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkaMiaRLgvY`, is it real to get quantity of seconds, which passed from the moment you press the button to start and until stop?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to measure?  The time a person actually watches a video? For example, if they navigate away from the page, does that count? Do you want to factor in if the video gets stuck buffering, or what?

Comment: @Gator_Python I want to get time, that a person actually wathed a video. I have logs and I try to get this time from there `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019312/python-how-to-get-duration-of-watching-the-video-by-the-user-from-logs` but I can't. I try to count  ID of some videos in the log, but it's less, than I have now. I try to test that and it's not common. Maybe speed of get requests afe different and depens on speed of wi-fi or 3g, so I don't know, how canI get it

Comment: Ok, I took a look at that question -- How are you getting those logs? What kind of access/monitoring capabilities do you have between the user and YouTube? Do you have physical access to the machine they use? Do they view the video through an internal webpage you manage? Proxy, or what?

Comment: @Gator_Python It's a tracker, that user can install and I can get all him logs. User install app  and some profile and I get logs through the proxy. A haven't got any capabilities between this apps and Youtube, I only get logs like this. I've find the metric `estimatedMinutesWatched` from `https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#estimatedMinutesWatched`. Maybe it can help me. But I can't find connections between it and Python

Comment: If you're the owner of the video with access to the Google account, you can use the YouTube analytics API to request that information using Python (or the API explorer, or any other langauge). Otherwise, you probably won't be able to request that analytic information from Google. Python is just an interface to their API; the metrics are all tracked by Google/YouTube

Comment: @Gator_Python I am not the owner of the videos. Do you think that there are not ways to get this information? Logs can't help me to detect the length of watching?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125624/discussion-between-gator-python-and-petr-petrov).

Answer (score 0):

If what you are measuring is the total time the **user** spent watching the video (including stalls/interruptions) then your strategy would work.

However, if you are looking to measure the video duration, then simply counting the number of seconds since "start" was pressed isn't very accurate. While your wall clock is still running, the video playback could jitter or even stall for a number of reasons.

- Slow network (buffering)
- Decoding/rendering delay. For instance, if you are trying to play a high-resolution video on a low-end device.
- Probably many other...